# Base of cone of arithmetic minimal covers

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, arithmetic-degree

By Borel determinacy (exercisce XIII.1.7 in Odifreddi) there is a cone of minimal covers in the arithmetic degrees.  Is the base of such a cone known?  A minimal such base?

For that matter, is it even known if there is a minimal base of a cone of arithmetic minimal covers?

Comment: I'd guess that by analogy with the Turing degree case that $0^{(\omega\cdot\omega)}$ would be the base of such a cone but I wouldn't be sure how to prove it since it's not obvious what's going to take the place of the $\omega$-REA operator and give you the needed inversion theorem.